# boost static_assert with message?

Tags: c++, debugging, boost, metaprogramming, static-assert

on 1.43 boost it seems that BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT just allows to put a boolean value, is there some alternative that allows me to display a message as well on the compile error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MPL has [`BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/assert-msg.html). E.g. using GCC 4.2. with this:

```
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG(false, THIS_DOESNT_WORK, (void));
```

... results in:

```
/path/to/file.cpp:42: error: no matching function for call to 
'assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************ (function()::THIS_DOESNT_WORK::************)())'
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(long) == 64 && "Must have 64-bit long!")
```

If your compiler supports the C++0x static_assert, you can do:

```
static_assert(sizeof(long) == 64, "Must have 64-bit long!")
```

Comment: i tried this but i got this error:

error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’

Comment: @lurscher That is the message that BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT always gives. Use BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG like Georg says to

Answer (score 0):

Boost 1.47 and later support [`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html). Usage:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(condition, msg)
```

If C++11 is available, or the compiler supports `static_assert()`, the error message will be `msg` string. Else the macro is treated as `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(condition)`